# Is it possible to send a variable to a page via a header redirect?

Tags: php, function, redirect, error-handling, header

I have a small error handling function that informs should inform the user of the error whilst on a redirect.

At present, it either redirects but does not pass through the variables $error and $prize or I can echo out the $error from the function.

I need to be able to redirect the user and then on the new page echo out the variable. Can i do this?

```
function error($error, $prize)
 {

    header('Location: ' . $form);
    echo $error . '<br />';
    echo $prize;

exit;
} // end error handler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it through GET:

```
$params = http_build_query(array('error'=> $error, 'prize'=>$prize));
header('Location: '.$form.'?'.$params);
```

destination page:

```
if($_GET) {
   $vars = $_GET;
   echo $vars['error']; 
   echo $vars['prize'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is often solved using session variables that show the error on the next page after the redirect. Basically, just check for session messages/errors on every page - and then you can add messages/errors to the user's session any time you need too.

Most PHP frameworks have this listed as "flash variables" under their session handling section.